# convert milliseconds and to local time and date javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium, epoch

I developing an android application using titanium in that i need to convert the Milliseconds time to UTC local time format.For that i tried several js but didn't worked out.

[Perfect link that converts milliseconds to local time](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

My millisecond time format will be ***1396250512***

I need to convert to local time like Monday, ***March 31, 2014 12:51:51 PM***

> new Date(+new Date * 1000).toLocaleString()

i used this to convert ms to local time..But Each time i trying the above code gives me different time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the Titanium. But using javascript here is the way.

```
var time = new Date().getTime(); // Get milliseconds
var date = new Date(time);// Milliseconds to date
alert(date.toString());


var time = 1396250512;
var date = new Date(time);// Milliseconds to date
alert(date.toString());
```

**Get time only**

```
var time = 1396250512;
var date = new Date(time);// Milliseconds to date
var t=date.toString().split(" ");
alert(t[4]);
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply @sajitha.. It working good, I having couple of doubts in it.., 1) The GMT showing 4.00 , in my response., 2) I need retrieve only time from it, Help me out..